# how to compute the number of total constraints in smtlib2 files in api

Tags: z3

I used the `Z3_ast fs = Z3_parse_smtlib2_file(ctx,arg[1],0,0,0,0,0,0)` to read file.

Additionally to add into the solver utilized the `expr F = to_expr(ctx,fs)` and then `s.add(F)`.

My question is how can I get the number of total constraints in each instance?

I also tried the `F.num_args()`, however, it is giving wrong size in some instances.

Are there any ways to compute the total constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Goal.size()` may do what you want, after you add `F` to some goal.  Here's a link to the Python API description, I'm sure you can find the equivalent in the C/C++ API: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#Goal-size

An `expr F` represents an abstract syntax tree, so `F.num_args()` returns the number of (one-step) children that `F` has, which is probably why what you've been trying doesn't always work.  For example, suppose `F = a + b`, then `F.num_args() = 2`.  But also, if `F = a + b*c`, then `F.num_args() = 2` as well, where the children would be `a` and `b*c` (assuming usual order of operations).  Thus, to compute the number of constraints (in case your definition is different than what `Goal.size()` yields), you can use a recursive method that traverses the tree.

I've included an example below highlighting all of these (z3py link here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/It5E ).

For instance, my definition of constraint (or rather the complexity of an expression in some sense) might be the number of leaves or the depth of the expression.  You can get as detailed as you want with this, e.g., counting different types of operands to fit whatever your definition of constraint might be, since it's not totally clear from your question.  For instance, you might define a constraint as the number of equalities and/or inequalities appearing in an expression.  This would probably need to be modified to work for formulas with quantifiers, arrays, or uninterpreted functions.  Also note that Z3 may simplify things automatically (e.g., `1 - 1` gets simplified to `0` in the example below).

```
a, b, c = Reals('a b c')

F = a + b
print F.num_args() # 2

F = a + b * c
print F.num_args() # 2

print F.children() # [a,b*c]

g = Goal()
g.add(F == 0)
print g.size() # number of constraints = 1

g.add(Or(F == 0, F == 1, F == 2, F == 3))
print g.size() # number of constraints = 2
print g

g.add(And(F == 0, F == 1, F == 2, F == 3))
print g.size() # number of constraints = 6
print g

def count_constraints(c,d,f):
  print 'depth: ' + str(d) + ' expr: ' + str(f)
  if f.num_args() == 0:
    return c + 1
  else:
    d += 1
    for a in f.children():
      c += count_constraints(0, d, a)
    return c

exp = a + b * c + a + c * c
print count_constraints(0,0,exp)

exp = And(a == b, b == c, a == 0, c == 0, b == 1 - 1)
print count_constraints(0,0,exp)

q, r, s = Bools('q r s')
exp = And(q, r, s)
print count_constraints(0,0,exp)
```

Comment: In addition, Can I also use the goal() to get the original assertions which are asserted in the smtlib2 instances? In other words, can F.arg() get all the original assertions? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, you can use `g.as_expr()` for a `Goal g` to return any expressions that have been asserted in `g` (i.e., after using `g.add(F)`.  Here's the Python API description: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#Goal-as_expr